# When will onscrollstatechanged(), onscroll() and getview() get called?

Tags: android, android-listview

I read the onscrolllistener documentation. However, when I try it out in code, it seems like it doesn't work as the document says. I have a customer adapter for the listview and I set onscrolllistener on listview. I added break point in onscrollstatechanged(), onscroll() and getView() method, when I scroll the list, it seems like they are called randomly. For example, when the activity with the listview gets created, onscroll() is called (I didn't scroll the list at all), then getView() is called multiple times (this is fine), then onscrll() is called again and getView() is called again. They are called alternatively 3 times at the begining and I didn't scroll the list at all. This is just one example of all the weird behaviors. Can any one give me an example with some explanation about when these 3 methods will be called? For example, when the user flings, what methods will be called in what sequence. Thanks!

Comment: i see the same confusing behaviour. For me, the onScroll() gets called dozens of time for even a small scroll, while the documentation says that it is called only when the scroll completes. This is absurd!